# scala for loop issue with assignment

Tags: scala, for-loop

```
val u = Array(1,2,3,4,5)                         
var outsideValue = 7                             

for{
 i <- 0 until u.size
 _= outsideValue = u(i)
 if(outsideValue == 2)
 j <- u
}
{

println(s"$outsideValue $j")

`Expected output is it should print all combination of Array with value 2, but it is not printing !!!`
```

NOTE: I know we can do it in simpleway 
But i want to know why above code is not working

Answer (score 0):

Let us first start with how will you do this in any other language,

Java

```
String[] u = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

for (int i = 0; i < u.length(); i++) {
  if (u[i] == 2) {
    for (int j = 0; j < u.length(); j++) {
      System.out.println("" + u[i] + ", " + u[j]);
    }
  }
}
```

JavaScript,

```
var u = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (var i = 0; i < u.length(); i++) {
  if (u[i] == 2) {
    for (var j = 0; j < u.length(); j++) {
      console.log("" + u[i] + ", " + u[j]);
    }
  }
}
```

And you can do it the more or less same way in Scala with `for-loop`. (Not to be confused with the concept of `for-comprehension`)

```
val u = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

for (i <- 0 until u.length()) {
  if (u(i) == 2) {
    for (j <- 0 until u.length()) {
      println(s"${u(i)}, ${u(j)})
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to use `for-comprehension` then,

```
val u = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

for {
  i <- u.filter(_ == 2)
  j <- u
} println(s"$i, $j")
```

As for "why your code does not work ?". The reason is that you are trying to use for-comprehension without really understanding these, which lead to a very strange looking and incorrect code.

`for-comprehension` in Scala works by using combinations of `map` / `flatMap` / `foreach` / `flatten` in various ways depending on the usage.

In this case, the above for-comprehension version is equivalent to the following `foreach` based version,

```
val array = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

array.filter(_ == 2).foreach(i => {
  array.foreach(j => println(s"$i, $j")
})
```

Comment: The distinction you're making here between "for loops" and "for comprehensions" in Scala doesn't exist. There is only one `for` keyword and it _always_ introduces a for comprehension that desugars in the way you describe.